# Java Chain Inheritance with Lombok and Guice Injections

Tags: java, inheritance, dependency-injection, guice, lombok

**EDIT: This question really should be around Lombok and Guice instead of vanilla java inheritance.**

I'm trying to implement a Java inheritance chain with Lombok and Guice injections, it works something like this:

Class 1

```
public abstract class Animal { 
    @NonNull protected String attr1;
    protected abstract void method1();

    void method0() {
        // Some code that uses attr1
    }
}
```

Class 2

```
public abstract class Mammal extends Animal { 
    @NonNull protected String attr2;
    protected abstract void method2();

    @Override 
    void method1() {
        // some logic that uses attr2
        method2();
    }
}
```

Class 3

```
public class Wolf extends Mammal { 
    @Inject @NonNull private String attr1;
    @Inject @NonNull private String attr2;
    @Inject @NonNull private String attr3;

    @Override 
    void method2() {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Out there in the `main` program I have code that calls `wolf.method1()`. The problem here is that only `wolf` has all the attributes needed (due to Guice injections), whereas all the fields in `Animal` are undefined. I suspect I can probably do it in Vanilla Java, but things are going to get super messy (I have 6 attributes in `Animal` class and 5 more in `Mammal`). Is there a way to mix-and-match lombok's annotations (@NoArgsConstructor, @AllArgsConstructor, etc) to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Your abstract classes cannot be directly instantiated even if they have public constructors, because they are declared abstract. If you prefer, you can make the constructors `protected` to indicate they are only available to subclasses.

Comment: The code as shown can't produce the error you mention, because it has a default constructor.

Comment: Thanks @khelwood, right that `abstract` classes can't really be instantiated, but why didn't the Java compiler catch this and stop complaining about not having a constructor?

Comment: Is this your complete code? As Mark already said what you posted shouldn't lead to an error (a warning maybe) since the compiler will add an empty constructor if no other constructor is present.

Comment: Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they still need a constructor because of the implicit call to `super()` in the subclass constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Your abstract classes cannot be directly instantiated even if you add public constructors, because they are declared abstract. If you prefer, you can make the constructors `protected` to indicate they are only available to subclasses.

> right that abstract classes can't really be instantiated, but why didn't the Java compiler catch this and stop complaining about not having a constructor?

Any class you write without an explicit constructor has an implicit no-args constructor. Any implicit no-args constructor implicitly calls its superclass's no-args constructor, even if that superclass is abstract. So if some class up the chain doesn't have a no-args constructor (because you explicitly gave it another constructor), then you code won't compile.

In the code you gave in your question, there are no explicit constructors, so every class *does* have an implicit no-args constructor. In your actual code, presumably you have written a constructor somewhere, which is why the implicit no-args constructor has not been added.

Comment: Is "void constructor" official terminology? I thought it was called "no-args constructor". Using "void" for a constructor could lead to confusion thinking void is a return type, and constructors don't have return types.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException You're right, no-args is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

1. use only interfaces for the entire hierarchy.
2. decouple behaviors and encapsulate them in separate classes.
3. use composition instead of inheritance, i.e. private SomeBehavior someBehavior; for every specific animal that needs it.

It will make your design better and solve the problem as well.

```
i.e. 
public interface Mammals {
}

public interface Animal extends Mammals {
}

public interface Dog extends Animal {
}

and 
public class TakeADump {
   public void dump() {
   }
}

public class TakeAPee {
   public void pee() {
   }
}
```

and then

```
public class Sheperd implements Dog {
    private TakeADump dumpService;

    private TakeApee peeService;
}
```

And now your dog can s... and p... :)

Also add

```
public class F... {
    public void f...(<Animal> animal) {
        // ... check it's an instance of the same or compatible animal or throw UnsupportedOperationException() if it's incompatible
    }
}
```

:D

Of course it will make sense to create an abstract Animal.

i.e.

```
public class AbstractAnimal {
        private TakeADump dumpService;

        private TakeApee peeService;  

        private F... f...Service;
}
```

then

```
public abstract class AbstractDog extends AbstractAnimal implements Dog {
}
```

and

```
public class Sheperd extends AbstractDog {
    public void lookAfterSheep() {
        Sheep sheep = SheepLocator.findNearest();
        // pee on a sheep
        peeService.pee(sheep);
        // dump on a sheep
        dumpService.dump(sheep);
        // f... a sheep
        f...Service.mount(sheep);
    }
}
```

So your mistake is using too much abstract when you can use interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

When you are implementing concept of inheritance with some argument constructor it is good practice to have one default (no argument) constructor defined there. Because while creating object of child class compiler internally will call constructor of parent class.
e.g

```
class ABC {

 }
 class XYZ implements ABC{

 }
 public class Test{
  XYZ obj= new XYZ() // this will internally call default constructor of XYZ and
  //in that first statement will super()--> this will call default constructor of class ABC
 }
```

if anyhow you have implemented argument constructor in parent class then compiler will  not implement default constructor implicitly we need to define it explicit to make call to super constructor from child constructor. Or do a explicit call to argument constructor from child constructor.